# Automatically logging in a user with KoaJS and PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, koa, koa-passport

I'm trying to automatically log in a user with [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/docs/login).

This is my current code:

```
myRouter.get('/signin', function* (next) {

    user = {...};

    var res = this.res; // needed for the function below
    this.req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log('error logging in user - '+err);
        return res.redirect('/'); // <--- line 439
    });
});
```

But when I run it, I get the error:

```
  error logging in user - TypeError: undefined is not a function
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at /srv/www/domain.com/app.js:439:32
      at /srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:49:48
      at pass (/srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:293:14)
      at Authenticator.serializeUser (/srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:295:5)
      at Object.req.login.req.logIn (/srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:48:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/domain.com/app.js:434:26)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
      at Object.dispatch (/srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-router/lib/router.js:317:14)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/domain.com/node_modules/koa-common/node_modules/koa-mount/index.js:56:23)
```

Comment: [Please do not put your question's tags into your title. You have the tag section for that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/248725)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The tags are not seen on the Google search results as clearly but only on Stackoverflow, so I do not agree with you at all.

Comment: If you feel like the tags _really should_ be there, then incorporate them organically. Like it said. In the thing I linked.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes On another personal note, this is opinion based. I feel it is being policed too much as it is, as long as the title explains what the question is up to then it is sufficient, hence the Google search. I will not be following any of the proposed "ways" anytime soon.

Comment: Well, I assume you read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thoroughly. If you did, you at least saw the links at the bottom. If you click on [this one](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), one of the first things it says is _not to put the tags in the title_. This is not a proposal or a suggestion.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Some of the most popular and knowledge giving answers are closed due to them being "off-topic". I am guessing you are in the minority corner of those who are strict with the "rules". This website has outgrown such practices and other practices as well, it's old fashioned. This is, after all, a user driven community.

Comment: ...Have you even _read_ what's on-topic? Those 'most popular and knowledge-giving answers' (incidentally, that should be 'questions') _are_ off-topic, since the site has gone from a generic programming questions site to a more specific one about specific problems. If anything, it's less old-fashioned now. But all that aside, if you don't like the site, no one is making you stay here. If you do like it, play by the rules, or bring it up on Meta to try to change them.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I am saying what the rules consider is off-topic are old-fashioned and that the practices of policing (which you are doing) are also old fashioned (in this specific area anyway title/tags). Indeed the site has gone from generic programming questions to something more, which imo is a damn good thing.

Comment: ...Okay, I'm getting really confused, so can we continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78729/discussion-between-karl-morrison-and-qpaystaxes) where it won't clutter up the comments? I think I've been misunderstanding what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick semi-derp moment and I realize to redirect in `koa` it does not use `res` but `this`, you must do the following:

```
var res = this; // needed for the next function
this.req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log('error logging in user - '+err);
    return res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it is just that `res` is called `response`, so just change
`var res = this.res;` in `var res = this.response;` and it will work fine. `res` does exist, but it is the Node http module response, not the Koa `Response` object, and therefore does not have any `redirect` method. The `redirect` is aliased to `this`, which is why you can use `this.redirect`, but it really is a `Response` method.
Take a look at http://koajs.com/#context for more details.

To avoid having to assign `this`, or `response`, you could just bind `this` to your function, I think it is cleaner in most cases:

```
myRouter.get('/signin', function* (next) {

    user = {...};

    this.req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log('error logging in user - '+err);
        return this.redirect('/'); // <--- line 439
    }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: Bravo! I did not know about `bind`, much cleaner!